# Looping through a object array with specific parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, d3.js

I need to accurately loop through my json array to match ids of positions and d3 objects ids.

Here's a snippet of the array (ruby on rails generated):

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "locations": [{
        "city_id": 1,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
        }, {
        "city_id": 2,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
        }, {
        "city_id": 3,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
        }, {
        "city_id": 118,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
        }, {
        "city_id": 117,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
        }, 
    ],
    "city": [{
        "id": 118,
        "name": "London"
        }, {
        "id": 117,
        "name": "New York"
        }, {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Miami"
        }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Duabi"
        }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Hong Kong"
        }
    ]
}
```

To collect the values of x & y i have a drag & drop functionality. When a drop an object i send off a post to update the positions of x & y values. However, it sends the update to in correct id as my loop isnt specific enough.

So now I have to find a way to collect the city locations & match them with d3 objects/cities.So I looped through like this:

```
   .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate("+json.locations[i].x+","+json.locations[i].y+")" ;})
```

But this just goes through the array without matching anything. So I would like essentially my loop to go through & to see if the ids correlate & then assign that location to the relevant d3 object. So if city id: 118 is dragged & dropped the location city_id:188 should update not city_id:1 which is the problem.

Is this possible.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
//i don't know where is it from
given_id = 118;

for(i=0;i<json.locations.length;i++) {
    var id = json.locations[i].city_id;
    if(id==given_id) {
        var x = json.locations[i].x;
        var y = json.locations[i].y;
        console.log(x+","+y);
        //do something with x and y
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LyQZ6/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - somewhat. given_id should come from the nested object "city" and collecting "id" from the city nest. I have therefore, instead tried var city = json.city[i].id; . But keeps throwing up that "id" doesnt exist. Any ideas

Comment: but I don't understand what is your case, when is it executed and how do you get _input_ data?

Comment: I'm getting my data through an ajax call which is defined as json. The data for the city was manually inputted and the locations are updated through a drag & drop function. So it would be executed when the mouse event is over.